# Synthesis algorithm, identify whether BCNF and find candidate keys

Tags: decomposition, 3nf

I have some problems regarding synthesis algorithms and finding candidate keys as I feel that the slides provided on my course merely gives examples of how they are inferred, with no explanation.

So, if we have a relational schema with the single relation R[ABCDE] with the functional dependencies: {AB->CD, C->AD, E->B},

So far I have gotten here:
The canonical shell is: C={AB->C, C->D, E->B} and the candidate keys are: EB AE and EC.

1) Apply the synthesis algorithm to find a lossless and dependency preserving 3NF decomposition.

I know how to check whether a decomposition is in fact lossless and dependency preserving, but not how to get there. Please see below:

i) Construct a canonical cover C for F

ii) Define C'={X union Y | X->Y "belonging to" Consol(C)} this I know

iii) Define C to be the subset of C' where all relations which is subsumed by another is removed. This I know if I think correct.

iv) Define C2 to be C if C already contains a superkey for R. Otherwise define C2 to be C union K for some key K of . This step I don't understand.

2) Motivate thoroughly whether the decomposition obtained in 3) is also in BCNF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe one for cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: *"So far I have gotten here: The canonical shell is: C={AB->C, C->D, E->B} and the candidate keys are: EB AE and EC."* The term *canonical shell* is new to me, but the candidate keys of R are AE and CE. The relation C has only one candidate key: AE.